# Getting deprecated warning in Node js while installing expo-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to install expo-cli for getting started with React native but I am getting the "request has been deprecated" error.

Comment: Hi! Can you share more details? How are you trying to install expo?

Comment: Hello, When I am trying to install expo-cli package, It stops and gives the message that "npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated".
your help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. I try to remove all of file in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm` such as expo.cli, etc.
2. and then run this command: `npm install -g expo-cli@3.5.0`

Comment: That's full removal, I wonder about clearing the cache first, then no 2.